# how to load .ani cursor in visual c++?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resources, cursor, animated

Ok so here are the steps i followed in creating a custom .ani cursor but no luck!
1. I created a resource.h file and added

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_H
#define RESOURCE_H

#define MyCustomBusyCursor 100

#endif
```

2 Then i created .rc file (by right clicking the project name and selecting Resource File).  But now i do not know how to add path to my .ani file. How would I load my cursor in main? I am guessing i will have to use LoadCursor() function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in case anyone is curious i used this code to load a custom cursor:

```
HCURSOR hCurBusy =  LoadCursorFromFile(TEXT("myAnimCursor2.ani"));
HCURSOR hCurStandard =  LoadCursorFromFile(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\Cursors\\arrow_m.cur"));


    SetSystemCursor( hCurBusy, 32512);
    Sleep(1500);
    /* or whatever you wanna do...*/
    DestroyCursor(hCurBusy);
    SetSystemCursor( hCurStandard, 32512);
    DestroyCursor(hCurStandard);
```

You do not need to do resource stuff. But the stuff i did is for changing system cursor, maybe for an app you might have to use LoadCursor function(s).